# jQuery execCommand for superscript and subscript not properly toggling

Tags: jquery, subscript, superscript, execcommand

I'm trying to create a text editor using jQuery and `execCommand`. Everything was going good until I noticed that both `superscript` and `subscript` aren't properly toggling.

This jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/k8F4P/) should illustrate the problem.

It is possible that it is simply my browser, but I'm using the latest version of Chrome for Mac.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Turned out the issue was that the stylesheet `normalize.css` was setting the `sub` and `sup` tags' `vertical-align` to `baseline` and this was preventing the correct toggling, but only in Chrome. The simple solution is to set `sub` to `vertical-align: sub` and `sup` to `vertical-align: super`.