# Bugs on document.execCommand('superscript') (or subscript) in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, execcommand

I was building my own **WYSIWYG** editor (using `document.execCommand()`), and i found some pretty strange bugs in **chrome** when testing.

Steps:
1. Highlight text
2. Superscript text
3. Bold text
4. Superscript text
5. Superscript text

After step 4, the text should not be superscript anymore, but is not. When inspect element,
Before step 4:

```
<sup>
    <b>
       Hello World
    </b>
</sup>
```

After step 4

```
<b>
    <sup>
       Hello World
    </sup>
</b>
```

and it worked after step 5.
http://jsfiddle.net/5fjzdxkk/

Tested and worked until step 4 on Firefox and IE. Not really understand how and why :( Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517839/jquery-execcommand-for-superscript-and-subscript-not-properly-toggling) to a similar question solved it for me.

Comment: Clearly that is a CSS issue, but this is not. I've even tried using the solution, but is not working. Did you try out the fiddle above? @jackadams49

Comment: fixed now in recent chromes https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=579039